# how to create bar graph in HTML5 for ipad web app

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html

I have ios native app for ipad with bar i want that app to conver to web app so i am making the app in HTML5 but problem is that how may i create bar graph for the HTML5 app.Is there any documentation or built in api for this.

Like for iOS we have EasyGraph like this

Comment: try looking at canvas or svg api's on HTML5. maybe they can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have a look to http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts

basically i'ld make basic bar graphs using DIVs and css

Comment: yes but graph will get value from user then created at run time

Comment: you can change the frame sizes of DIV at runtime. Or Use canvas or svg as writes tomexsans  for a more graphical.

Comment: and here a HTML5 tutorial : http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-bar-graph/

Comment: and here a canvas version : http://html5laboratory.com/creating-a-bar-chart-with-canvas.php